# Magento 1.9 RWD theme responsive cms content

Tags: magento

How can I use bootstrap in cms pages using RWD theme ? Is there anyway to setup this option?

Example:

CMS -> Homepage -> class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"

No style apply when I check frontend

Answer (score 0):

You can add the (Bootstrap) CSS to CMS pages by using the cms_page_view layout handle and adding it to the head block. In the cms.xml file in your module layout directory (you may need to create it yourself), add the following (this assumes you already have bootstrap.css in your skin/css directory):

```
<cms_page_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>skin/css/bootstrap.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
    </reference>
</cms_page_view>
```